# Computed property was assigned to but it has no setter - a toggle component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a simple switch toggle component in Vue where it has a v-model and @updated. But I can't seem to change the model when the user toggles the switch. First I was getting the error to avoid mutating a prop directly. But now I am getting another error.

> [Vue warn]: Computed property "isSwitchOn" was assigned to but it has
>   no setter.

The component is meant to be used like this

```
<iswitch v-model="switchGender" @updated="handleUpdatedGender" />
```

Here is the component itself

```
export default {
    template: `
        <span
            @click="toggleSwitch"
            :class="{ active: isSwitchOn }">

            <span class="toggle-knob"></span>
        </span>
    `,

    props: ['value'],

    methods:
    {
        toggleSwitch()
        {
            this.isSwitchOn = !this.isSwitchOn

            this.$emit('input', this.isSwitchOn)
            this.$emit('updated')
        }
    },

    computed:
    {
        isSwitchOn()
        {
            return this.value
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is triggered by this statement: `this.isSwitchOn = !this.isSwitchOn`. You are trying to assign a value to a computed property but you didn't provide a `setter`.

You need to define your computed property as follow for it to work as a `getter` and a `setter`:

```
computed:
{
    isSwitchOn:
    {
        get()
        {
            return this.value
        },
        set(value)
        {
            this.value = value
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it is not advised to mutate a prop directly. What you could do is to add a new data property and sync it with the `value` prop using a watcher.

I think something like this will work:

```
props: ['value'],
data()
{
    return {
       val: null
    }
},
computed:
{
    isSwitchOn:
    {
        get()
        {
            return this.val
        },
        set(value)
        {
            this.val = value
        }
    }
},
watch: {
   value(newVal) {
       this.val = newVal
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I indeed needed a watcher for value.

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties are by default getter-only, but you can also provide a setter when you need it. Check [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

```
computed:
{
    isSwitchOn() {
        get() { return this.value }
        set(val) { this.value = val }
    }
}
```

**Alternative way:**

In your parent component:

```
<iswitch ref="switcher" @input="methodForInput" v-model="switchGender" @updated="handleUpdatedGender" />

methods: {
  methodForInput(event){
    this.$refs.switcher.isSwitchOn = event;
  }
}
```

In your child component:

```
export default {
    template: `
        <span
            @click="toggleSwitch"
            :class="{ active: isSwitchOn }">

            <span class="toggle-knob"></span>
        </span>
    `,

    data() {
      return {
        isSwitchOn: false
      };
    },

    methods:
    {
        toggleSwitch()
        {
            this.isSwitchOn = !this.isSwitchOn

            this.$emit('input', this.isSwitchOn)
            this.$emit('updated')
        }
    }
};
```

**Updates 3:** Sorry, didn't include parent component at first.

Comment: By setting this.value you are mutating a prop.

Comment: @Liga I have updated with an alternative way, not sure it whether it will help.

Comment: I found the solution. I had to add a value() watcher for the value prop. Thanks!